# Convert HTML to word document with python-docx module

Tags: python, html, python-docx

My text is on database with HTML code because when I added to database PyQt5 converted text to HTML. My text is here:

How should I convert html format to text and add word document with text formatting(example: bold, italic)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also use, in python3.x from with html document:

```
from htmldocx import HtmlToDocx

new_parser = HtmlToDocx()
new_parser.parse_html_file("html_filename", "docx_filename")
#Files extensions not needed, but tolerated
```